# What is the best way to create multiple forms in Django using Bootstrap for updating values in a JSONField dictionary?

Tags: python, html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create an update form in Django, which I suppose, is not really complicated, but I need to know which way is a standard way to implement it. I try to simplify it. So let's imagine:

`models.py`:

```py
class Building(models.Model):
    """ORM representation of the Projects"""

    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False, null=False)
    project = models.JSONField(default=building_default_value, blank=False, null=False)
```

A simplified example of project:

```json
{
        "floor": {
            "Stahlbeton": 200,
            "Estrich": 50,
            "Sauberkeitsschicht": 50,
            "Abdichtung": 10,
            "Dampfsperre": 2,
            "Schaumglas": 120,
            "Extrudiertes Polystyrol (XPS)": 120,
        },
        "roofbase": {
            "Stahlbeton": 200,
            "Abdichtung": 10,
            "Dampfsperre": 4,
            "Kies": 50,
            "Extrudiertes Polystyrol (XPS)": 180,
        },
        "wall": {
            "WDVS Verklebung und Beschichtung": 15,
            "Steinwolle-Daemmstoff": 140,
            "KS-Mauerwerk": 175,
            "Gipsputz": 15,
        },
    }
```

Now I want to have an update form in my HTML page, that user is able to edit each number of this material. For example it should be rendered something like this:

```
Floor:

Stahlbeton = (place to modify number)

Estrich = (place to modify number)
```

and so on for all other keys.

I tried to use `{% bootstrap_form form %}`, but the problem is that with this command, there are going to be just 2 forms for name and project, and I won't be able to break it down to have multiple forms for each value in the project dictionary.

Here is also my `views.py`:

```py
class BuildingUpdate(generic.UpdateView):
    """Update existing buildings"""

    model = models.Building
    fields = {"name", "project"}
    template_name = "building_update.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("building:buildings")

    def form_valid(self, form):

        building = form.save(commit=False)
        building.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

I would appreciate any hint, idea or link to help solve this challenge.

Comment: I'd recommend adding another model called `Project`. It adds so much flexibility. Also this approach gives you an easy way to update `Project` via a modelform.